# Change parent frame url if iframe url changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have iframed a page:

```
<iframe src="http://externalwebsite.com/test.html" scrolling="no" height="400px" width="400px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I want to change the parent url to `http://mywebsite.com/succes.html` if the iframe url changes to `http://externalwebsite.com/succes.html`

I was trying to figure it out with JavaScript but I didn't manage to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Due to security concerns there is likely no way to do this without proxying the external site

Comment: You can detect when it loads a new page but not what that page is when not same domain http://plnkr.co/edit/ebnk244eJrwREIJuI3JC?p=preview Iframes are very restricted due to *"same origin policy"*

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe id="frameId" src="http://externalwebsite.com/test.html" scrolling="no" height="400px" width="400px" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Bind to the frame.onload event in the parent window.

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frameId'); 
frame.onload = function(e){
   if(frame.src === 'http://externalwebsite.com/succes.html' ){
      window.location.href = 'http://externalwebsite.com/succes.html';
   }
};
```

Try `frame.src='someUrl';` for test.

Comment: did you test this? Demo link above won't give update url and also jQuery has no `onload` so it won't fire as written. Would either be `frame[0].onload` or `frame.on('load'...`

Comment: :( for me it did not worked, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: You are right charlietfl. It is either the code you mention or 
var frame =document.getElementById('frameId');